# Regex escape ( ' " ? - ! . \ | ) and return the first five words from a text

Tags: php, regex

how to return the first five words from the string

**text** = A database? have't is. collection! of information—preferably some/even 
(related information) and preferably? organized. v1.0 lates, tech=tech

pattern = `^(\w+\s+)([^\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)`     - > *this return the whole string*

**however if I tried to add a quantifier {0,5}**

pattern = `^(\w+\s+)([^\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*){0,5}`   - > *this dose not match at all*

I just want to return the first 5 matches from this text above or any other text contains characters such as above **text**

Comment: Since you're using PHP, why not just get the first 5 items in the array it returns by using PHP itself?

Comment: it would be better if i make it with regex - so i don't have to do extra work

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't match at all. It matches all right, except that you don't have a capture group containing what there is in the first regex. And your question isn't clear. What do you mean by 'first 5 matches'? What is the result you expect?

Comment: all i want is to return the first five words from the text above - yes it's matches but, it matches the whole text i just want to match the first five words only -

Comment: thanks guys for the help , sorry i am not good English speaker

Comment: Okay, and do you want to have the punctuations in those words? It would have been clearer from the start if you have typed the result you wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab at it -

For Unicode:

```
 # ^(?:[^\pL\pN]*[\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN_-]|\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP_-]))*){1,5}

 ^
 (?:
      [^\pL\pN]* [\pL\pN]
      (?:
           [\pL\pN_-] 
        |  \pP
           (?= [\pL\pN\pP_-] )
      )*
 ){1,5}
```

For ASCII:

```
 # ^(?:[\W_]*[^\W_](?:\w|[[:punct:]_-](?=[\w[:punct:]-]))*){1,5}

 ^
 (?:
      [\W_]* [^\W_]
      (?:
           \w 
        |  [[:punct:]_-]
           (?= [\w[:punct:]-] )
      )*
 ){1,5}
```